# Using a network switch, router or other hardware like a pi to limit access to a specific ethernet port

Tags: networking, firewall

I'm trying to look for a way to secure a NVR on my local network and I've considered buying a router like the TL-R600VPN to segregate my network from the NVR, however I'm not convinced this is the best course of action since the untrusted VLAN's aren't accessible from trusted VLAN's. I'd like to separate the NVR from my local network so an attacker getting access to an IP camera's Ethernet jack is a more managed problem, as well as cut the NVR off from the internet and only give back temporary access when I've given a login to some sort of firewall/captive portal. I was thinking a raspberry pi with two NIC's might work for this, but I'm not sure where to start with scripts/software to bridge the two NIC's temporarily with a predefined timeout of, for example, 30 minutes.

Comment: How's that any different from adding a firewall rule to temporarily allow the necessary connections between VLANs for 30 minutes? (Is that something the router cannot do?)

Comment: @user1686 From what I've read about the TL router it has no way of allowing any communication between VLAN's

Comment: That's kind of a pity. On normal routers it's a matter of configuring the firewall rules in whatever way you want.